# Why is my groupby returning incorrect values for the 'product' column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the maximum price paid by each user, as well as which product was purchased, into a dataFrame. When I run the below code, it returns exactly what I'd expect, but the 'product' column is incorrect.

Original data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[123,'xt23',20],
                   [123,'q45',2],
                   [123,'a89',25],
                   [77,'q45',3],
                   [77,'a89',30],
                   [92,'xt23',24],
                   [92,'m33',60],
                   [92,'a89',28]], columns=['userid','product','price'])
df
```

which generates this original dataFrame:

```
    userid  product price
0   123     xt23    20
1   123     q45     2
2   123     a89     25
3   77      q45     3
4   77      a89     30
5   92      xt23    24
6   92      m33     60
7   92      a89     28
```

**This is what's not working:**

```
df.groupby('userid').max()
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
userid  product price   
77      a89     30
92      m33     60
123     a89     25
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
userid  product price   
77      q45     30
92      xt23    60
123     xt23    25
```

The values in the product column are incorrect. If I add 'product' to the groupby, the max prices are still correct, but I only want to see one price & product per user. I also tried setting numeric_only=True but that did not solve the issue.

Does anyone know why the product values don't align with the original data?

Comment: `df.loc[df.groupby('userid')['price'].idxmax().values, :]`? Pandas has `GroupBy.idxmax`, As for reason `max` is applied on each the columns of groups

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the desired output efficiently.

```
idx = df.groupby(['userid'])['price'].transform(max) == df['price']
print(df[idx])
```